# Getting the strongly typed HTML helper value into a simple parameter type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ActionMethod and I'm trying to bind a string from a value supplied by a strongly typed HTML helper:

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{        
    public ActionResult Save(string name)
    {
        return Content(name);
    }
}
```

My view contains complex objects... and I'm trying to use strongly typed helpers as such:

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Sample

@using(Html.BeginForm("save", "sample")) {
   @Html.TextBoxFor(x =>x.Product.Name)
   <input type="submit" />
}
```

I know that the TextBox renders with the name `Product.Name`

```
<input id="Product_Name" name="Product.Name" type="text" value="">
```

and that I can bind to a complex `Product` type with the name `product`:

```
public ActionResult Save(Product product)
{
    return Content(product.Name);
}
```

or use the Bind attribute to bind to a property with a different name:

```
public ActionResult Save([Bind(Prefix="Product")]Product p)
{
   return Content(p.Name);
}
```

but how do I get it to bind to just a string value?

```
public ActionResult Save(string name)
{
    return Content(name);
}
```

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the full prefix (the value of the name attribute) of the input field. For example:

```
public ActionResult Save([Bind(Prefix="Product.Name")]string name)
{
   return Content(name);
}
```

If you desire even more control you can always use a [custom model binder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imodelbinder.aspx):

```
public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    // insert implementation
}

public ActionResult Save([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomProductModelBinder))]string name){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, knew it had to be something simple that I was just missing.